# Use multiple words in a result search query

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have made a result query with a few managed properties. We can now search for the metadata columns what works fine. I can't use multiple words in the search for the title column. Here is my query

```
path:https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx RefinableString1: {searchTerms}   OR RefinableString2: {searchTerms} OR RefinableString3: {searchTerms} OR Title: {searchTerms} ContentType:xxx
```

The result are fine when I use two words for two different managed properties but if a documentset has the title "Salesjob Invoice Red 1150" I can't use two words to fine tune my search in the title. I tried this query but the result is the same.

So how can I use multiple words to search in the Title or in the managed properties?

Answer (score 0):

Per the Keyword Query Language (KQL), we could use multiple words in the managed properties, you could just build your search query like this:

```
title:"Salesjob Invoice Red 1150"
```

Please read this article for more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference

Comment: I tried your solution en i think this should be the query: 

"path:https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx {?Title:{searchboxquery}*} OR+AND {?RefinableString1:{searchboxquery}*} OR ContentType:xxx"

But i got no result. So i would like to search for a title and for and extra RefinableString1 but it looks i can only use OR in the query instead AND/OR.